# Add new files into .deb package you're building

Tags: packaging, deb, build

How do you add new files, eg custom init script into .deb package that you're building?

Comment: Depends on how you're building the .deb file. Please give more details, but generally, you just adjust the "rules" file or the ".install" files.

Answer (score 5):

Flint, the simplest way is to add the file to `debian/install`, or `debian/binary-package-name.install`. The format of the file is

```
source/relative/to/source/root destination/relative/to/system/root
```

So if you want to put contrib/scripts/admintool into /usr/bin/foo-admintool You'd do:

```
contrib/scripts/admintool usr/bin/foo-admintool
```

dh_install, which reads these, is fairly smart and will try to set permissions to the right values.

Specifically for init scripts, there is `dh_installinit`. You should probably read `man dh_installinit` to understand it fully, but basically if you have

```
debian/package-name.foo.init
```

It will be installed as `/etc/init.d/foo` and setup to start on installation/boot.

Subsequently, if you write an upstart job

```
debian/package-name.foo.upstart
```

Will be put in as `/etc/init/foo.conf`

And a symlink will be created as `/etc/init.d/foo` that points to an upstart wrapper for sysv compatibility.